Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation when calling a C function from Swift
I'm trying to call this C function from Swift and getting a compilation error:

// header
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt_callback(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, size_t (*param)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*));

// c file
CURLcode curl_easy_setopt_callback(CURL *curl, CURLoption option, size_t (*param)(char*, size_t, size_t, void*)) {
    return curl_easy_setopt(curl, option, param);
}

Error message:
Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation

Using this code:
typealias Callback = @convention(c) (
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer?,
    Int32,
    Int32,
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer?
) -> Int32

func testConnection() {
    let curlHandle = curl_easy_init()
    
    // https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en
    curl_easy_setopt_string(curlHandle, CURLOPT_USERNAME, "***@gmail.com")
    curl_easy_setopt_string(curlHandle, CURLOPT_PASSWORD, "***")
    
    curl_easy_setopt_string(curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL,
                         "imaps://imap.gmail.com:993//%5BGmail%5DSent%20Sent%20Mail");
    
    let callback: Callback = { ptr, size, nmemb, userdata in
        return 0
    }
    
    // Error on the next line: Type of expression is ambiguous without a type annotation
    curl_easy_setopt_callback(curlHandle, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, callback); 
    
    print("curl_easy_perform")
    let res = curl_easy_perform(curlHandle);
 
    if(res != CURLE_OK) {
        print("curl_easy_perform failed\(res)")
    } else {
        print("success!")
    }
    
    curl_easy_cleanup(curlHandle);
}

Not sure what am I doing wrong.
I wrapping the libcurl's curl_easy_setopt because Swift does not like variadic functions. If there is a way to get rid of this wrapper - I'd be happy to do so.
I'm using Xcode 15.4 and targeting iOS 17.5. The static libcurl has version 8.10.1

I'm trying to call this C function from Swift and getting a compilation error It might help to edit your question and post the exact error message. Also, any relevant compiler command line options.

Are you trying to make general-purpose libcurl bindings in Swift, or just set specific options your app needs?
If the 2nd, you can try defining specific strongly typed wrappers in C, e.g. my_curl_set_cookie_jar (CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR) and my_curl_set_hsts_write_function (CURLOPT_HSTSWRITEFUNCTION).
The callbacks have specific strongly typed function pointer signatures.  See e.g. CURLOPT_HSTSWRITEFUNCTION, which gives the callback function signature.
It's just that the signatures vary by parameter.
The exception is that the user data is not strongly typed.  E.g. CURLOPT_HSTSWRITEDATA is passed back as void *clientp for CURLOPT_HSTSWRITEFUNCTION.
If you wrap each needed curl_easy_setopt parameter as a separate wrapper function, you can strongly type them.
